# How to pick multiple videos as well as photos from gallery using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to pick both photos and videos from gallery.

I have done a few things like picked photos but not showing the videos. I have used BSImagepicker library and I have't found any video related thing in this library. If anyone have done such kind of work or know about any other library which picks both photos and videos please refer.

```
import UIKit
import Photos
import BSImageView
import BSImagePicker

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let pickerController = BSImagePickerViewController()
    var SelectedAssets = [PHAsset]()
    var PhotoArray = [UIImage]()
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: Any) {
        pickImages()
    }

    func pickImages() {
        self.bs_presentImagePickerController(pickerController, animated: true, select: { (asset: PHAsset) in
        }, deselect: { (assets: PHAsset) in
        }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) in
        }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) in
            for i in 0..<assets.count {
                self.SelectedAssets.append(assets[i])
            }
            self.convertAssetToImages()
        }, completion: nil)
    }

    func convertAssetToImages(){
        if SelectedAssets.count != 0 {
            for i in 0..<SelectedAssets.count {
                let manager = PHImageManager.default()
                let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
                var thumbnail = UIImage()
                option.isSynchronous = true
                manager.requestImage(for: SelectedAssets[i], targetSize: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500), contentMode: .aspectFit, options: option, resultHandler: { (result, info) in
                    thumbnail = result!
                })
                let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(thumbnail, 0.7)
                let newImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                self.PhotoArray.append(newImage! as UIImage)
            }
            hcArray = PhotoArray
            self.imageView.animationImages = self.PhotoArray
            self.imageView.animationDuration = 3.0
            self.imageView.startAnimating()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the designs of the libraries aren't great...

Here, Fresh out of the oven:
https://cocoapods.org/pods/CameraRoll

I'll add a readme and improve it but it works well.

first, add this to your plist

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>To Find images</string>
```

Then Import

```
import CameraRoll
import Photos
```

Then when you want to use it,

```
   let cr = CameraRoll()
    // For pitures use .Image mode
    cr.present(in: self, mode: .Video) { (assets) in
        // Returns array of PHAsset
        }
    }
```

Use helper functions to convert

```
    let cr = CameraRoll()
    cr.present(in: self, mode: .Image) { (assets) in
        if let assets = assets, let first = assets.first {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                AssetManager.sharedInstance.getImageFromAsset(phAsset: first) { (image) in
                    self.imageView.image = image
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: [!] Unable to find a specification for `CameraRoll`